# Print button from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I put an iframe for my all 100pages, and i want to add "Print" button to that iframe. So that every page has a button in it from iframe. 
But when click Print button only prints iframe page. I want to print whole seeing page.

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="window.self.print();" />
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="parent.window.focus();" />
```

I tried several codes but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you can add the function:

```
function printMe() {
  window.print()
}
```

And then from the button of the iframe you can call:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printMe();" />
```

#### UPDATE

In the very same logic of @Manwal you can get the container by id or class and then focus on this.
Example:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="document.getElementById('.container').focus();document.getElementById('.container').print();" />
```

Comment: First of all, your goal is to accomplish the print. Why dont you take the print button from the iframe and put in the parent window?

Comment: I'm not able to edit parent windows, i can only make changes in iframe file.

Comment: Your update seems like it works, but you should user querySelector instead of getelementById (since you're getting the class, not ID)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="parent.window.focus();window.print();" />
```